# Give permissions to user of the same role

Tags: 7, users

I'm working in a site and I've to set node permissions (edit) so that a user can edit a node that is owned by a user of the same role.
If I have the role "redactor" I can edit any node that is owned by a user that as the role "redactor".
Is there a module that do this?

Or I've to write a custom module?

Answer (score 1):

You can used module [content access](http://drupal.org/project/content_access), he does that easily.

> This module allows you to manage permissions for content types by role and author. It allows you to specifiy custom view, edit and delete permissions for each content type

[image: content access]

Or you have [node access](http://drupal.org/project/nodeaccess) which add a tab on each node to control permission for this node (you can configure role or user) I never really used it because there's no very stable version for d7.

Comment: I know content access but are you sure that is it useful for me? I don't have to set permissions generally to content types & roles. I need that if I have a role (redacator, for example), I could edit nodes that are owned by other users with the "redactor" role.

Comment: Sorry, i misunderstood the subtility of your question. In fact, it was possible to do that programmatically with `node access` but it seems that in drupal 7 it doesn't work anymore (i tried to reinstall it and i have a fatal error when i save the form) You could with this module give an alias for all your role, after i think it was easy to set it for the node.  But you're right you can do that with `nodeaccess_userreference`.

Comment: Actually, i did that with `references` module by auto-assign  a user that was linked to the content with : `$form['field_reference']["und"][0]['uid'] = array( "#type" => 'value',"#value" => $user, );` SO i think i possible to do that for users of the same role.

Comment: Ok, I'll write a simple custom module that use hook_node_presave. In this hook I call a view that tells me all users with the same role of the author and I add a user_reference to the node for every users

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution could be the use of http://drupal.org/project/nodeaccess_userreference or http://drupal.org/project/nodeaccess_userreference

With this modules I can set programmatically, when I save the node, a user-references field to all users of a role.